# Fatal: Could not read from remote repository with Bonobo on IIS

Tags: git, bonobo

I've installed Bonobo 3.3.0.0 in IIS on 2008 R2 system. The web interface works well, I can create repositories, add users, etc.
But when I try to clone from it I get this:

```
C:\svn\lan>git clone http://git.robertivanc.com/lanweb.git lanweb
Cloning into 'lanweb'...
Username for 'http://git.robertivanc.com': rob
Password for 'http://rob@git.robertivanc.com':
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

If I type the wrong password I get Fatal: authenthication failed, so auth seems to be ok.
The App_Data permissions seem to be ok, as repositories get created.

I'm using forms auth.

If I go directly to this url in the browser I get 
404 Page Not Found

The page you were looking for wasn't found. Please try again or contact the system administrator.

The only thing in the errors log is this:

```
Trying to load native SQLite library "C:\inetpub\bonobogit\Bonobo.Git.Server\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll"...
Trying to load native SQLite library "C:\inetpub\bonobogit\Bonobo.Git.Server\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll"...
Trying to load native SQLite library "C:\inetpub\bonobogit\Bonobo.Git.Server\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll"...
Trying to load native SQLite library "C:\inetpub\bonobogit\Bonobo.Git.Server\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll"...
Trying to load native SQLite library "C:\inetpub\bonobogit\Bonobo.Git.Server\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll"...
```

I've switched the app pool bitness to see if this has got anything to do with it, but no. The sqlite .db file is there in App_Data and does seem to get updated.

I've also set up this repo as anonymous and I get the same error, the only difference is that it doesn't ask me for the username/pwd.

What else can I do to debug this?

Update:

I've now done a fiddler trace (after also moving the app to a subdirectory and making it an application, so to be as close to the installation instructions as possible).

Anyway, the server returns this:

```
GET http://git.robertivanc.com/Bonobo.Git.Server/lanweb.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack                         HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/1.9.4.msysgit.2
Host: git.robertivanc.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-advertisement
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 24 Dec 2014 17:52:17 GMT
Content-Length: 34

001E# service=git-upload-pack
0000
```

Comment: Had a similar situation, in IIS7 I had bonobo converted into a website rather then a web application, I also disabled all forms of authentication (allowed anonymous use) and it worked for me.

Comment: Hm, I already have it as a website..

Comment: have you tried playing with the auth settings in IIS7 ? is there a proxy between you and the server ? have you tried reaching the server using it's IP address ?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @joab - I did, though it is so long ago I have no clue what I did, sorry :(